# jQuery: How to filter the multiple types of data using one text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

I am newbie to Jquery.Purpose is to show the stock for different Sizes using one text box.
For eg.If Search Box containes 180 as well as 375 then it show the stock of both sizes.
Now,My code only works for single size.
HTML:

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Search</td>
<td><input type="text" id="search" name="search"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 <table id="table">
                     <tr>
                        <th>Size</th>.
                        <th>Stock</th>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>180<td>
                        <td>250</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>180<td>
                        <td>750</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>375<td>
                        <td>1000</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>750<td>
                        <td>1500</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>1000<td>
                        <td>250</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>180<td>
                        <td>250</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>375<td>
                        <td>200</td>
                     </tr><tr>
                        <td>375<td>
                        <td>250</td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Expected Output:

```
Search Box: 180,375
Size      Stock
180        250
180        750
180        250
1000       250
```

Is it possible ,If yes then Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Taking Advantage Of `:contains()`**

Since you are already using jQuery, you can take advantage of the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and use a little bit of logic to generate a few of them for each of your terms.

**Checking Only The First Column**

If you only wanted to target the first column (i.e. Size), then you could do that as seen below by finding elements that contain your search term and then showing/hiding the appropriate rows :

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
      var term = $(this).val();
      if(term.trim().length == 0){
        // Show everything if no text is present
        $('#table tr').show();
      }
      else{
         // Build your selectors
         var selectors = term.split(',').map(function(t){
             return '#table tbody tr :first-child:contains("' + t + '")';
         });
         // Hide all of the cells
         $('#table tbody tr').hide();
         $(selectors.join(',')).each(function(){
             // Find the parents of each child and display them
             $(this).closest('tr').show();
         });
     }
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Search</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>180
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>180
          <td>
            <td>750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>375
          <td>
            <td>1000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>750
          <td>
            <td>1500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1000
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>180
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>375
          <td>
            <td>200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>375
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var term = $(this).val();
        if (term.trim().length == 0) {
          $('#table tbody tr').show();
        } else {
          // Build your selectors
          var selectors = term.split(',').map(function(t) {
            return '#table tbody tr :first-child:contains("' + t + '")';
          });
          $('#table tbody tr').hide();
          $(selectors.join(',')).each(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').show();
          });
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Checking Both Columns**

Likewise, if you wanted to search either of your columns, that becomes quite a bit simpler as you can just use the `:contains()` call on the `<tr>` element.

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
      var term = $(this).val();
      if(term.trim().length == 0){
        // Show everything if no text is present
        $('#table tr').show();
      }
      else{
        // Build your selectors (map each term to a contains statement)
        var selectors = term.split(',').map(function(t){
          return '#table tr:contains("' + t + '")';
        });
        // Hide all of your rows and then target the selectors to display them
        $("#table tr").hide().filter(selectors.join(',')).show();
      }
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Search</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>180
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>180
          <td>
            <td>750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>375
          <td>
            <td>1000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>750
          <td>
            <td>1500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1000
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>180
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>375
          <td>
            <td>200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>375
          <td>
            <td>250</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var term = $(this).val();
        if (term.trim().length == 0) {
          $('#table tbody td').show();
        } else {
          // Build your selectors
          var selectors = term.split(',').map(function(t) {
            return '#table tbody tr:contains("' + t + '")';
          });
          $("#table tbody tr").hide().filter(selectors.join(',')).show();
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks John, I've updated providing examples of each of the approaches (i.e. searching a single column, searching both, etc.).